# PHP password validation error

Tags: php

I'm creating a login for a website using PHP but when I try to login I always get the same error "You forgot to enter your password." An error I included if the user forgets to enter the password, however I have been entering a password. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The PHP:

```
//check for a password and a match against the confirmed password:
if (empty($_POST['pass1']))
{
    if($_POST['pass1'] != $_POST['pass2'])
    {
        $errors[] = 'Your passwords did not match.';
    }
    else
    {
        $p = trim($_POST['pass1']);
    }
}
else
{
    $errors[] = 'Your forgot to enter your password.';
}

if (empty($errors)) //if everything is okay
{
//register the user in the database
require_once
('../mysqli_connect.php'); //connect to the DB
```

The HTML form:

```
     <p>Password: <input type="password" name="pass1" size="15" maxlength="20"/>*</p>

     <p>Confirm Password: <input type="password" name="pass2" size="15" maxlength="20"/>*</p>
```

Thank in advance!

Comment: It should be `if( !empty( $_POST[ 'pass1' ] ) )`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code says to send the error message if the password is NOT empty (`else` case of empty). Either switch the `then` and `else` blocks around, or put a `!` before `empty`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's always a small thing, I've been going round in circles for an hour, how depressing.

Comment: Always the way. It looks like you confused yourself by having `if empty` be the "everything is ok" case when checking for errors, and applied the same reasoning to the "is there a password" case.

Comment: Now to continue debugging the rest of it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: No problem, good luck! Also, remember to mark this answer as Accepted when the 15 minute minimum question age is up ^_^

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!empty($_POST['pass1']))
{
    if($_POST['pass1'] != $_POST['pass2'])
    {
        $errors[] = 'Your passwords did not match.';
    }
    else
    {
        $p = trim($_POST['pass1']);
    }
}
else
{
    $errors[] = 'Your forgot to enter your password.';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//check for a password and a match against the confirmed password:
if (!empty($_POST['pass1']))
{
    if($_POST['pass1'] != $_POST['pass2'])
    {
        $errors[] = 'Your passwords did not match.';
    }
    else
    {
        $p = trim($_POST['pass1']);
    }
}
else 
{
    $errors[] = 'Your forgot to enter your password.';
}
....
```

Answer (score 0):

You logic is wrong.
You code show that "If you pass1 is **EMPTY**, compare the `pass1` AND `pass2`"
The correct code is

```
if (!empty($_POST['pass1']))
{....}
else{....}
```